# Creating a geometrically decaying pause loop

Tags: batch-file, delay

So I am working on creating a batch file game analogious to a "Memory" game. (ie where the player is presented a list of objects for a short time, then asked to repeat the pattern)

My problem comes in how to decrease the time the pattern is exposed to the player as the round # increases.

Here is my current code:

```
@echo off
set /a y=50
set /a x=1000

:foo
set /a y=%y% + %y%
set /a x= %x% - %y%
echo %y%
echo %x%
ping -n 10 -w %x% 127.0.0.1 > nul
goto foo
```

When run, the above code does present x and y values that change as expected, however the wait time is always the same. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly why dont you use `sleep`? It would work fine (type `sleep /?` for more info)
However, here is another way of doing this with `for /l` loops

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set score=0
title Memory Test : Current Score = !score!

for /l %%a in (0,1,20) do (
Rem In the above sequence, increase 20 to the amount of times you want the test to be performed
set number[%%a] = !random!!random!
echo Number: !number[%%a]!
set /a wait=21-%%a
set /a wait=!wait!*1000/4
sleep -m !wait!
cls
set /p "input=What was the last number youy saw? "
if !number[%%a]! equ "!input!" (
set /a score=!score!+1
Echo Correct !
title Memory Test : Current Score = !score!
)else(
Echo Incorrect! Coreect Answer = !number[%%a]!
)
)
echo Calculating score...
pause
cls
echo.
if %score% leq 14 set msg="Nice Try! But you can do better!"
if %score% geq 15 set msg="Good Job! Your on your way to the top!"
if %score% equ 20 set msg="Your So Close! Almost a perfect socre!"
if %score% equ 21 set msg="You got a perfect score! Woderful!"
Echo %score%/21 : %msg%
echo.
pause
```

And that should work fine. Note you can change how long the test goes for, but for the first game they'll have a  bit more then 5 seconds to study the question, and in the last round a quarter of a second!

Mona

Comment: Tell me if you find any problems, I haven't got the chance to test this. Also I'm about to add the ability to give blank answers. If you do give no answer the program will end.

Comment: Fixed the no answer problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for such an awesome in depth response! I actually figured out my problem. (I missunderstood the ping formatting, duh!) The main reason I was using my method was because I wanted the decrease in time between each round to increase as the rounds increased. (which is why I chose a geometric series). However I also found that I needed a termination condition, so I added a division. Here is my code now:

echo off

set /a y=5005

set /a x=5000

set /a z=75

:a

set /a y= (%y% + %y%)/4

set /a x= %x% - %y%

echo %y%

echo %x%

PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w %x% >NUL

goto a

Comment: `sleep` is not actually a microsoft command.  You might have added it to your system but it's not default in any Microsoft OS.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the ping/wait trick to work, the ip address must not exist. 127.0.0.1 is your own computer, so it has no opportunity to timeout since the ping response is successful and immediate.

Instead, choose an ip address that doesn't exist. E.g. 10.20.30.40 (assuming that doesn't exist.)

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the 10 in this to give approximately second resolution.  Is that sufficient for your code?

```
ping -n 10 127.0.0.1 > nul
```

This is another option for later windows.

```
timeout /t 10 >nul
```